# Qt / C++ - Traverse Menu with Keys (Not Mouse)

Tags: c++, qt, menu

I'm trying to do what you'd see in a video game menu while playing with a controller, but with a keyboard and QT/C++.

I don't know where to begin and because I don't know what the term is I don't know what to search for. Can't find anything on Google.

I am making a menu where left/right/up/down select items. No mouse input.

Can anyone help with a starting point, please?

Comment: In your window override [event](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#event) method. In that method check if event is [key event](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qkeyevent.html) (`event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress`), then check if any of cursor keys is pressed (`keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Up`), and if so, do what ever you wanted to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample method for handling key presses.

- The class `Widget` is assumed to subclass `QWidget`
- `_rows` member variable is number of menu rows
- `_row` member variable is the currently selected row index starting from 0
- `updateSelectedMenuItem()` is a method for doing whatever you want to do to have certain menu item selected, such as moving some marker on screen or changing colors.

---

```
// overriding superclass method
void Widget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *ev)
{
    switch(ev->key()) {
    case Qt::Key_Up:
        if (--_row < 0) _row = _rows-1;
        updateSelectedMenuItem();
        break;
    case Qt::Key_Down:
        if (++_row >= _rows) _row = 0;
        updateSelectedMenuItem();
        break;
    default:
        // call superclass event handler method
        QWidget::keyPressEvent(ev);
    }
    // Note: QKeyEvent starts with isAccepted() == true
}
```

Note that this will rely on normal keyboard repeating, so it will behave the same as if you pressed up/down in any normal application where cursor moves. If you want different behaviour (for example if you are controlling a game, instead of moving in a menu), you should also override `keyReleaseEvent`, so you know when key is actually pressed down and released again.